# Any way to create minimal example shapefile with fake data in R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I am wondering how to create minimal example shapefile of certain countries such as `US`, `Germany`, or `Brazil` with fake data. I am new with geospatial data and it is nice to know how to create minimal geospatial data in R. I need reproducible shapefile because I want to create my minimal solution on it and test my approach.

How can I make this happen minimal shapefile of certain countries with fake data in R? Any quick approach to do it? Any idea?

**Update**:

I am going to create shapefile of certain countries such as `US`, `Germany` or vice-versa by `state` or `county` level but fill it with fake random data for reproducible use. Any better idea?

Comment: A *minimal example* of ***what***? What kind of data? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: Perhaps easier to use one of the built-in data sets from one of the R packages and modify some attributes? You might need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @Vince Sorry if my question is not crystal-clear to you. I want to create shapefile of certain countries (`US`,`Brazil`, or `Germany`) with certain administrative level (state or county or other types of administrative level). Any smart move?

Comment: @Spacedman sorry for my late reply, I just updated my post with few line more specification. Any better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume that you want polygon outlines of those countries. I will leave it up to you make *fake data*. I am also going to assume that you in fact want on-disk **shapefiles** and are not using the term as shorthand for *spatial data*.

```
library(sf)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

us      <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
germany <- st_as_sf(map("worldHires", "Germany", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
brazil  <- st_as_sf(map("worldHires", "Brazil", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(0,0,0,0))
plot(us$geometry)
plot(germany$geometry)
plot(brazil$geometry)

write_sf(us, "us.shp")
write_sf(germany, "germany.shp")
write_sf(brazil, "brazil.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is that possible to produce shapefile for Germany with respective administrative level (state, province, county and so on, just like Eurostat shapefile). Any better idea?

Comment: I doubt there are existing built in polygons with this detail. You probably need to download them separately apart from R.